# When i click button in gridview it does't work

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I am a beginner of Asp.net, making l small project but having big problems, :) ...
Right now I have a situation, I used `gridview` to retrieve data from Access database and I done that, I added buttons in grid view. When I click on button the following error comes

> Server Error in '/E Shop' Application. Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

HTML

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Width= "100%" CellPadding="3">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table class="style17" width="100%" border=" 0">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="100%" width="25%">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" Height="144px" 
                                ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64, " + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) Eval("Picture")) %>' 
                                Width="158px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" height="100%" width="75%">
                            <table align="right" class="style17">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" style="font-size: 15pt; color: #0000FF" 
                                            Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Brand") %>' 
                                            CssClass="style18" Font-Size="15pt"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="51px" 
                                            ImageUrl="~/Images/orange_addtocart-trans.png" Width="159px" 
                                            onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <strong>Rs:</strong><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                                            Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>' CssClass="style18" Font-Size="15pt"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Color") %>' 
                                            CssClass="style18" Font-Size="15pt"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="51px" 
                                            ImageUrl="~/Images/orange_addtocart-trans.png" Width="159px" 
                                            onclick="ImageButton2_Click" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Condition") %>' 
                                            CssClass="style18" Font-Size="15pt"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Material") %>' 
                                            CssClass="style18" Font-Size="15pt"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table class="style17">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" height="100%" width="30%">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Height="144px" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64, " + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) Eval("Picture")) %>' 
                        Width="193px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

c#

```css
public partial class Shirts : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\Products.mdb"));

        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Shirts";

        cmd.Connection = con;

        OleDbDataAdapter Adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Adaptor.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
  //      Session["Title"] = "Label7.Text";
    }
    protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
      //  Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }
}
```

Please Help me to make the buttons work
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an event handler for controls present in `Gridview` control like this, because they are not static and they repeat for each item coming from the datasource for the Gridview.

When a button is clicked in Gridview, [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.100).aspx) event is raised, so you need to write your logic in this event by identifying your control, something like this:-

To identify each control individually in Gridview RowCommand event, you need to add `CommandName` & `CommandArgument` properties to your control:-

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="51px" ImageUrl="~/Images/orange_addtocart-trans.png" Width="159px" OnCommand="Foo" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
```

Here, **CommandName** is used to identify the control which raised the event and **CommandArgument** is used to identify the current row.
Finally, you can read them in code behind like this:-

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Foo")
  {

    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

    // Add you logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: I got your point but as i told i am begginer So..
I done above things but got compilation error. Why?
Line 45:              </td>
Line 46:     <td align="right">
Line 47:                                                         <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="51px" 
Line 48:                                                             ImageUrl="~/Images/orange_addtocart-trans.png" Width="159px" 
Line 49:                                                             OnCommand="Foo" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"

Comment: @ImranTishna - Thats because you have used `OnCommand` instead of `CommandName`. Please refer this MSDN link and follow all the steps, it 'll help you:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Rahul Bhai, i am still unable to solve it... Please tell which time you are free, i will send you teamviewer id, and i beleive it will take a few minutes for you to solve it.. i will be thankful to you for this favour.....

Comment: @ImranTishna - What problem your are facing?

Comment: Again this Server Error...    :(
Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: @ImranTishna - I don't know why you are still using the click event of image button, completely remove that code it will not work, `Foo` was just an example, you need to identify that event in Item databound.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the Example you provide, i set commandname and commandargument properties and in Rowcommand event i try to same steps like example but again i got that Error

Server Error in '/E Shop' Application.

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Source:

```html
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="51px" 
                                                         commandname="Foo" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                                                            ImageUrl="~/Images/orange_addtocart-trans.png" Width="159px" 
                                                            onclick="ImageButton1_Click2"/>
```

C#

```js
public partial class raff : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\Products.mdb"));

        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Shirts";

        cmd.Connection = con;

        OleDbDataAdapter Adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Adaptor.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }


    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender,
    GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
        {
            // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
            // CommandArgument property.
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
            // from the Rows collection.
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

            // Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.
            Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
        }

    }
    



    
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
  //      Session["Title"] = "Label7.Text";
    }
    protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
      //  Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //  Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }


    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }
```